# How to totally remove the whole root administrator thing?

Tags: xubuntu, root

I don't want to get snagged up on the root administrator business in Ubuntu. I want to be able to put things in directories and remove them without long command line conversations (that I have to Google phrases for) with my computer. For example, deleting the stock screen background jpegs should be as simple as hitting the delete key, but is a whole epic journey of deep research into how it can be done. The holdup is the root administrator. So how to get rid of - totally nuke to oblivion - the whole root administrator thing in Ubuntu? I'm using Xubuntu 14.04.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, some folders have to have certain owners and permissions to make Ubuntu work. You can, however, just run the file browser as root. In Xubuntu, the file browser is `thunar`. So, running `sudo thunar` will let you do anything in the file browser as root.

If you want a way to run Thunar as root without typing anything, you can go to `/usr/share/applications` and open `thunar.desktop` with Gedit. Edit the `Exec=...` to read `Exec=sudo ...`. You're going to have to run Thunar as root to edit this file. After saving it, make a link to it on the desktop, and you'll have your file browser running as root. You can even pin it to the launcher. If you need help with anything comment.

**Be warned: Running Thunar as root is *very* dangerous. Use it with caution.**

Comment: Alright, so I can't actually nuke permissions. Since I am using Thunar as the file manager, I have taken your advice and typed sudo thunar , and that worked. I have yet to try the more permanent solution you have shown. It may be that if the simple sudo command persists for an entire session before logging out, that might be enough.

Comment: Good! I didn't see you were on Xubuntu, but I'm glad you were able to adapt it. I'll edit the answer to be correct.