# Why is running an Ubuntu file manager as root dangerous?

Tags: root

I have read that running Ubuntu apps as root is dangerous. Why? Is it still dangerous on a personal non-networked computer? In particular, why shouldn't I run the file manager as root administrator?

Comment: @muru It sort of is, but I think he means running programs as root, like Nautilus.

Comment: @muru Or you could edit it. I know what's being asked after helping on a previous question by the same person about managing files owned by root. http://askubuntu.com/questions/665012/how-to-totally-remove-the-whole-root-administrator-thing/

Comment: @muru Just did. The request was put in.

Comment: I think the old question does answer my question. The problem though is that I didn't think to search 'why is it bad', so I never saw that old question before posting my new question. I'll leave it to experienced SE members to decide what to do.

Comment: Maybe leave this question with a pointer to the old question. After all, my question here does ask it in a slighlty different way, that may be found in cases where the other won't be.

Comment: Foot: shoot. Easiest as root.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's only dangerous because you can delete important files accidentally. On servers and such, giving `root` a password can make the computer vulnerable to attack, since the all-powerful `root` is accessible to use to delete files. The only reason logging in as `root` or using programs as `root` that I can think of is the possibility of accidentally deleting something that you didn't want deleted or modified.